# Solve contrained nonlinear optimization problem by MATLAB

Tags: optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I know in MATLAB there is a `fmincon` to solve this kind of problem. But I really don't know how to use it for my problem.

**Question 1: Find optimal $u$ to**

$u^TDx-\frac{\mu}{2} |u|^2 \rightarrow max$

$|u_{i}| \le 1$

where $x$ - given 1D column vector, $\mu$ - const, |.| - $L_2$ norm, $D$ - gradient operator, $u$ - 1D column vector.

**Question 2: Do above problem and below problem have same optimum?**

$-(u^TDx-\frac{\mu}{2} |u|^2) \rightarrow min$

$|u_{i}| \le 1$

If without constraint, this is right. However, there is constraint, do they have same optimum? I don't want to formulate the dual problem.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) on fmincon? It should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: This is  a convex quadratic optimization problem for which the optimization toolbox (as well as similar toolboxes from external vendors) will be much more suitable in terms of performance and accuracy than fmincon. Search under quadprog.

Comment: Can I transfer this problem to min by add minus before functional and unchange the condition? I don't want to formulate the dual problem. If without contraint, $f\rightarrow max$ and $-f\rightarrow min$ have same optimum, but there is a constraint.

Comment: For Q2, the answer is yes. You can multiply your objective function by $-1$ and minimise it subject to the same constraints. I agree with Michael's comment that you're better off using `quadprog` instead of `fmincon`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most optimization solvers require an objective function (by default) in minimization form. Multiplying a maximization by negative one is one way to reliably transform the objective to a minimization statement, even with constraints. I created an [fmincon tutorial with source code (see method #2)](http://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/MatlabOptimization) for a problem with an objective function, equality constraint, and an inequality constraint or you can use MathWorks' [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) or [quadprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) documentation.

If you do solve this problem numerically, you should avoid the use of an absolute value operator $\left | u_i \right |<1$ as an inequality constraint but instead use an upper and lower bound on the variable ($u_i\lt 1$ and $u_i\gt -1$). Using an absolute value operator may cause problems for gradient based solvers that require continuous first and second derivatives.

Comment: How can I formulate objective function in Matlab with undefined number of argument? $u=(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)$ Just like this `objective = @(u) u(1)+u(2)+.......+u(n)+u(1)*u(1)+u(2)*u(2)+....+u(n)*u(n);`